# What is a synthetic pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, gdb

I was debugging some C++ code in GDB and I found out that some calls were making use of a so-called "synthetic pointer". Googling around did not produce any meaningful result. Searching here on SO, most questions with "synthetic" in their title refer to some Java feature (even if they suggest me that "synthetic", in this context, could mean "something generated artificially by the compiler").

E.g., look at this backtrace, took from one operation, performed in the constructor of `MyClass`, over one class member called `m` (this code has been compiled with `-O2`):

```
#0  MyClass (arg=..., this=<synthetic pointer>) at somefile.h:144
144     m->lock();
gdb$ print this
$1 = (MyClass * const) <synthetic pointer>
gdb$ print *this
$2 = <optimized out>
```

The stack trace above clearly states that `this` is a pointer to an object that has been optimized out, but how is it possible that a method (i.e., its constructor) has been called on it? My wild guess is that, even if the enclosed object (`m`) is actively used in the code, some optimizations let the compiler decide that the enclosing object (`this`) is not really necessary. Since the method call `m->lock()`, that cannot be optimized out, must be emitted somewhere, the compiler creates a "fake" (synthetic?) object, located nowhere in memory, just to wrap `m`.

I do not have a strong compiler experience, so I do not know if this conclusion really makes sense. Could someone please shed some light on this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A compiler can determine whether `this` is actually dereferenced (i.e. using the specific CPU details, not the general C++ rules). If a method doesn't actually dereference `this`, there's no need to have a phyiscal representation available.

[edit]
In the comments, jww mentioned another case. A singleton has only one copy, so a smart compiler can treat its members as globals. That means the address of `singleton->foo` is just the constant `&singleton + offset(foo)`. As a result of this optimization, the singleton methods don't need to actually dereference `this` either to get access to the singleton members, so it again can be optimized out.

Comment: Yes, my `MyClass` object was constructed, never referenced and, some time later, destroyed; the only important operations were the side-effects of the constructor/destructor (for the record, it is a custom implementation of a scoped lock). So this must be the case. Thank you.

Comment: Is that what a synthetic pointer actually is (when "this" is optimized out)?  I feel that this answer can be interpreted as a side note that yes an object can be optimized out if never referenced but not that the "synthetic pointer" is the case of "this" being optimized out.  I see synthetic pointer in stack traces and I'm not sure how to interpret it's not the regular <optimized_out> message.

Comment: @JoeyCarson: It's all a bit philosophical. Formally, objects either exist or they don't. After an optimizer has run, objects may exist partially, to the degree necessary for the observable behavior program. It's up to the debugger to fake real objects, and that's not a science.

Comment: Interesting.  So could this mean, for example, that an object was optimized out, but maybe in a way that the optimizer tries to make it seem like it's still there for some reason?  Consider for example, a function that takes a few parameters, one of them being a pointer to an object.  If that object was optimized out somehow, yet there is a call to that function that must check whether the pointers is NULL or not, clearly something must go in as a parameter, because assuming the function isn't inline, it exists at some static location in memory and can't be altered, as other callers dependent.

Comment: In this case, I could see that it's a NULL pointer, but it's synthetic because it's just there because it has to be, for instance in CPP, this function does not define a default value, something needs to go in there.  And in the case of a stack trace, if I were looking at the call to that function, I might see that NULL was passed, and consider oh that's not right, why is that pointer not being set?  But instead the <synthetic_pointer> message is there to deter me from thinking anything is actually wrong.  My apologies for this comment spam.

Comment: @JoeyCarson: That's just one of those tricky things. The optimizer may see through the function call, notice there's only a `ptr==NULL` check and just put in any random non-NULL value instead of `this`.

Comment: I have to agree with Joey. I just ran into the *synthetic pointer*. The class is a static Singleton that detects CPU features. It clearly runs at load time, and it is clearly referenced in subsequent code. From reading the comments, I'm pretty sure you know what you are talking about; the problem is in the terse answer. Maybe the answer should be improved based on feedback in the comments?